# Restcomm USSD Gateway TPS limitation

Tags: java, gateway, ussd, restcomm

I would like to know whether USSD Gateway has any kind of TPS limitation. I've read at documentation:
***"How many transactions per seconds will the hardware handle?
As mentioned above, you can have more than 1.000 TPS on a single server but having a distributed topology with HA (High Availability), LB (Load Balancing) and Failover will make your services scale better."***

I have developed a client test application, which exchanges echo messages with a server application through the Gateway.
I am getting something about 1.3k ~ 1.4k TPS on my single server, but the machine resources are far from being fully stressed (about 30% CPU and 25% Memory), which leads me to think that I could have yet more TPS performance. Is there a way to increase resources usage, to get a bigger TPS rate, or the infra-structure of the Gateway (JAVA/JBoss/JSLEE) limits the solution to no much more than 1000 TPS, as stated in the documentation?

Thanks in advance!